# Edit State File of ElasticSearch 7.3

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have one ElasticNode 7.3.2 in my cluster which has crashed and since then isn't able to restart, but still contains important data (last replicas are on this node).

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: failed to find metadata for existing index indexname-2019.06.23 [location: ORVU14kLSf6kIv8ULliijA, generation: 178]

i dont care about this special index, can i just remove this one from the state file? I already tried to remove it via an HexEditor, but then he complains about are not valid hash-checksum ;)

I already tried to decode it via SMILE, but it seems that *.st files dont follow the exact specifications only partially.

Does someone has an idea? Or a good tool to edit it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar case in which I corrupted my index settings with invalid similarity settings. Unfortunately, the settings were written to file by ES without validity check and afterwards I could not open the index again. So I got the index meta data from `data/nodes/0/indices/<index UID>/_state/state-xx.st` and figured out how to load it, change it and store it back again. I used ES 5.4 so the code I give here will be slightly different in ES 7.x. It goes like this:

```
import org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexMetaData;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.NamedXContentRegistry;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class RepairIndexSettings {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        // Load the existing, possibly corrupt index file
        IndexMetaData d = IndexMetaData.FORMAT.read(NamedXContentRegistry.EMPTY, Paths.get( "indexstaterepair","_state", "state-11.st"));

        // Create new IndexMetaData by copying all the valid meta data from the original and removing or fixing
        // the corrupt settings.
        Settings.Builder sb = Settings.builder();
        for (String key : d.getSettings().keySet()) {
            if (!key.contains("similarity"))
                sb.put(key, d.getSettings().get(key));
        }
        IndexMetaData newd = IndexMetaData.builder(d).settings(sb).build();

        // Write the new index state to file
        IndexMetaData.FORMAT.write(newd, Paths.get("indexstaterepair"));
    }
}
```

I replaced the original state file with the new one and could open and use the index normally afterwards.

You would have to use another `MetaData` subclass but I think it should be quite similar otherwise.

Comment: This was a lifesaver! Though I did not want to edit anything - my case was a failed ES setup and I could not even fire API commands via curl - so it was kind of blackout with absolutely no hope. When I used above trick at least I could pick specific indexes and incrementally recover things. Thanks buddy!

Comment: Glad it helped! :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to edit any files inside the data directory by hand. If you're getting an exception like `failed to find metadata for existing index` then there's something quite wrong with your storage, or something other than Elasticsearch has modified its contents. In either case, this has corrupted this node. The best path forward is to wipe the data path and start the node afresh so that Elasticsearch can rebuild any lost shards from elsewhere in the cluster or else restore them from a recent snapshot.